# Preg match to remove tracking code from all URL's in XML

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to extract all the urls from an XML file, excludeing the the tracking code in the url:

Here's an example of a URL, they all follow the same format

```
http://www.domain.com.au/category/pXXXXXX?uni_id=XXXXXX&cid=1_demo_1
```

So the only thing that changes between the domains is XXXXXX which is a numerical value

The end result I want is

```
http://www.domain.com.au/category/pXXXXXX
```

I have tried to use preg_replace in the below code but it ended up replacing the whole URL with a random (i think) number

```
$data = preg_replace('/http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com.au\/[^\?]+([^.]+)/','',$data);
```

Comment: `strpos()` for `?` and cut with `substr()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match URLs in the XML with `preg_match()`:

```
preg_match("(http://[^\s]+|ftp://[^\s]+)", $input, $matches);
```

Then, you should use `preg_replace()` and should only match the part of the string that needs to be removed:

```
foreach($matches as $value)
{
    preg_replace("(\?[^\s]+)","",$value);
}
```

Comment: i've changed the post slightly - worried that your answer would replace all data with ? in it.

Comment: Um, *why* did you use `[h|f][t]{1,2}p` instead of `http|ftp`? It's a) easier to read, b) shorter, c) correct (doesn't match fttp).